# SQL Server spams in event log on every call of extended proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, logging, event-log

I've wrote an extended stored procedure in dll.
Every time I call it, SQL Server wrote useless "Information" in Windows Event Log (Windows Logs\Application):

```
Event Type: Information
Event Source:   MSSQLSERVER
Event Category: (2)
Event ID:   17055
Date:       04.09.2009
Time:       14:54:57
User:       N/A
Computer:   4STORYTESTDB
Description:
8128 :
Using 'D:\AllProjects\mantainance\TBalanceSP.dll' version 'UNKNOWN' to execute extended stored procedure 'TGetAccountBalance'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

I call this procedure very often, 10-20 times per sec. and Event Log becomes "zasrannym" ("full of s..t"), as we say in Russia.

How can I disable this log message?

Comment: *Not* a useful link: http://sqlexceptions.blogspot.com/2009/01/sql-error-8128-severity-10.html

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it could be that the account used to execute the stored procedure doesn't have enough access rights to execute itself or some action inside the stored procedure. This would be a bug and I think you'd prefer to fix the bug instead of hiding it. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm shure, where is no bugs, cause the same message logging then I exec one of built-in extended procedures, e.g. [master].[sys].[xp_sprintf]

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005 you can control whether or not SQL will log events to the Windows Application Log with the "-n" startup parameter.

See this link for the MSDN Documentation.
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737%28SQL.90%29.aspx)